# wordpress gallery - how can I customize it/add jquery to it?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gallery

Hi I am trying to manipulate the default gallery in wordpress by adding jquery to cycle through my images rather than displaying it as individual picture links. However, I cannot seem to find the files to change - I would like to figure out how to customize the default gallery (preferably without a plugin).. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### You can filter the default gallery shortcode and replace it with your own shortcode function.

`add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'your_gallery_func', 10, 2);`

#### In `your_gallery_func` You will need to mimic the default gallery and extract the atts:

```
/*
* Extract default gallery settings
*/
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
    'id'         => $post->ID,
    'itemtag'    => 'dl',
    'icontag'    => 'dt',
    'captiontag' => 'dd',
    'columns'    => 3,
    'size'       => 'thumbnail',
    ), $attr));
```

#### Next you will need to get all the images attached to the post or return if none:

```
$attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    if ( empty( $attachments ) )
        return '';
```

#### Next write your code that you want to output assigning it to a variable then return it at the end of your function.

This is just an example:

```
/**
 * Open the gallery <div>
 */
$output .= '<div id="gallery-'.$id.'" class="content gallery gallery-'.$id.'">'."\n";
$output .= '<div id="thumbs" class="navigation">'."\n";

/**
 * Loop through each attachment
 */
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) :

/**
 * Open each gallery item
 */
$output .= "\n\t\t\t\t\t<li class='gallery-item'>";
$output .= '<a class="thumb" href="' .  $link[0] . '" title="' . $title . '">';
$output .= '<img src="' . $img[0] . '" alt="' . $title . '" title="' . $title . '" />';
$output .= '</a>';
/**
 * Close individual gallery item
 */
$output .= "\n\t\t\t\t\t</li>";

    endforeach;

/**
 * Close gallery and return it
 */
 $output .= '</ul><!--.thumbs-->'."\n";
 $output .= '</div><!--#gallery-wrap-->'."\n";

    return $output;
```